# jquery: retrieving data is not working

Tags: jquery

I am getting two times each data. I can't find the error..

```
$.getJSON('edit_scripts.php', {group:$('#group').val()}, function(data) {
  var select = $('#subject');
  $('option', select).remove();

$.each(data, function(index, array) {
  for(var i=0;i<data.subject.length;i++){
  //console.log(data.subject[i]);
  select.append(new Option(data.subject[i], data.scriptID[i]));
 }
});
```

I checked in console. But can't figure it out.

Console output of data:

Object {subject: Array[6], scriptID: Array[6]}
scriptID: Array[6]
0: 1
1: 2
2: 9
3: 13
4: 14
5: 15
length: 6
**proto**: Array[0]
subject: Array[6]
0: "Question 1↵"
1: "Question 2↵"
2: "Awesome Sales Pitch"
3: "wedW"
4: "just check"
5: "test pass"
length: 6

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question, which part of your code is not working?

Comment: Can you please post an example of what data looks like? You can use the output from `console.log(data);`

Comment: @Vlad: It's in there .. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess this :

```
$.each(data.subject, function(index, value) {
    select.append(new Option(value, data.scriptID[index]));
});
```

Comment: I need to use for loop, because data is in array form. And I want to put all that data into dropdown menu.

Comment: $.each handles both arrays and objects just fine ?

Comment: Edited the answer based on how the data object looks.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: I got your point, that .each is responsible for return data twice. I am not that much efficient in jquery. I don't know how to make changes over there.

Comment: Perfect. Done. I have just deleted .each .. There is only for loop now.. thank you very much guys..